# How to Define a Field in Solr to Retrieve Documents with "travel" but not variations like "traveling", "travels"?

Tags: solr

Lets say that I have following documents:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "content": "I love to travel around the world."
}
{
  "id": 2,
  "content": "Traveling is my favorite hobby."
}
{
  "id": 3,
  "content": "I have traveled to many countries."
}
```

How should I configure the "text" field in Solr to ensure that a query:

```
text: "travel"
```

returns the document with ID 1? I am not interested in documents where is ONLY the variation of word "travel".

Comment: That will depend on what the analysis chain for the field is - remove any stemming filters, reindex, and you should get what you're looking for. Stemming is the term used for converting a word to its stem - i.e. "traveling" to "travel" - so if you remove that filter for a field the token will remain as it was present in the input text. You probably want to define a separate field for this instead of changing an existing field, since you probably have cases where you want to actually use the stemmed form.